# How to pass functions to capture events in custom component in Meteor with Blaze

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I want to know how to bind/set template-passed-parameter-value to click event of an item in the template in Meteor.

I'm using Meteor 0.7.0.1 with Blaze UI package. My main idea is to build a re-usable custom components in Meteor with Blaze template engine.
I have the following component which is working fine at the moment but I want this to be more customizable and remove some dependencies.
This is my component template named `postLinks`

```
<template name="postLinks">
    <div id="link-popover-wrapper" >
        <ul class="link-popover">
        {{#each linkOptions}}
            <li><a tabindex="-1" class="link-action" id="link-{{value}}" href="#">{{label}}</a>
            </li>
         {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>
```

This `postLinks` component is used in the `myPostItem` helper.

```
Template.myPostItem.events({

    'click .post-item-link-picker': function (evt, tmpl) {
        var tmpPostId = this._id;
        var tempData = {linkOptions:[{label:'Favorite', value : 'favorite'},{label:'Wish list', value : 'wishlist'},{label:'Later', value : 'later'}, {label:"Read", value:"read"}]};

        var linkContent = Template.postLinks(tempData);
        $(".item-link-picker").popover({
            content: linkContent, html: true, placement: 'bottom', trigger: "manual",
            template: "UI_POPOVER_TEMPLATE"});
            $("#item-link-picker-"+tmpPostId).popover('show');
    },

    'click .link-action': function (evt, tmpl) {
        //.... some code here to update link selection in db
    }
});
```

Above code is working fine and I want to improve it to have following

- Pass item click event externally to be bind to `link-action` like

After above two changes it will look like :

```
Template.myPostItem.events({

    'click .post-item-link-picker': function (evt, tmpl) {
        var tmpPostId = this._id;
        var tempData = { itemClick:function(){}, linkOptions:[{label:'Favorite', value : 'favorite'},...]};
        var linkContent = Template.postLinks(tempData);
        $(".item-link-picker").popover({
            content: linkContent, html: true, placement: 'bottom', trigger: "manual",
            template: "UI_POPOVER_TEMPLATE"});
        $("#item-link-picker-"+tmpPostId).popover('show');
    }
});
```

I lack knowledge how/where to bind that passed event handling function to `link-action` elements in template or helper. I really appreciate if anybody could help to find a way to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You go the other way around and use `jQuery` event triggering system, so

```
Template.myPostItem.events({
  'click .link-action': function (evt, tmpl) {
     $(evn.target).trigger('post-link-action', this /* extra data */);
  },
});
```

This event can be easily catched in any parent template:

```
<template name="someOtherTamplate">
  {{> myPostItem}}
</template>


Template.someOtherTemplate.events({
  'post-link-action': function (evt, tmpl, extra) {
     // the user of your component can define their custom behavior here
   },
});
```

Please note that the event `extra` parameter will only be supported in the next **Meteor** release. Currently (0.8.0) it is included in the `devel` branch.